# How To Print Descendants Of GAE NDB onto Jinja2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, jinja2

So I have been tinkering for a while with jinja2 and google app engine. I am just writing a small toy app on my spare time; the app has a webpage that displays the ten most recent posts along with its comments.

All of the blog posts print fine onto the page by using the following within the google data store, after the Post object is created and stored in the database of course.  I use the following query to get the ten posts to be displayed.

```
recent_blog_posts = ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY created_at
DESC LIMIT 10;")
```

The blogpage.html code below:

```
{% block content %}
{% for post in recent_blog_posts %}
    <div>
        <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
        <pre>
            <p style="max-width: 100%;">{{post.post}}</p>
        </pre>
        <p>By: {{post.by_user}}</p>
        <!-- this is where I want the comments to go (explained below)-->
        <h4>Leave A Comment:</h4>
        <form method="post">
            <textarea name="comment" value="{{comment}}" style="height: 50px; width: 200px;"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="post_key" value="{{post.key}}">
            <br>
            <button>Comment</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I just iterated over the ten objects in the query above to print all of the blog posts. However, this is where it gets tricky for me.

I create a new Comment instance with the following:

```
new_comment = Comments(comment = comment,
user = user.name, parent = ndb.Key(Posts, int(post_key)))
new_comment_key = new_comment.put()
```

When I print the new Comment instances onto the screen, just to see, they all print out correctly with the right parent and their own ids.

Now this is where I am not sure on how to take each Comment instance and print it with its corresponding post. How can I accomplish that?

I have searched everywhere, and even added this to the html template above. (In place of the comment from the html template above)

```
{% for comment in comment_query %}
    {{comment.comment}}
{% endfor %}
```

With the query below:

```
recent_comments = Comments.query(ancestor=ndb.Key(Posts, int(new_string))).order(-Comments.created_at).fetch(limit=3)
```

This obviously just prints out all of the Comments instances for all of the Posts instances on the page.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just form the output list in the backend itself.

```
recent_blog_posts = ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY created_at
DESC LIMIT 10;")
posts_with_comments = []
for post in recent_blog_posts:
    recent_comments = Comments.query(ancestor=post.key).order(-Comments.created_at).fetch(limit=3)
    posts_with_comments.append([post, recent_commmnets])
```

Then iterate over `posts_with_comments` in the template like

```
{% for post,comments in posts_with_comments %}
    <div>
        <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
        <pre>
            <p style="max-width: 100%;">{{post.post}}</p>
        </pre>
        <p>By: {{post.by_user}}</p>
        <p> Comments: </p>
        {% for commnet in comments %}
           {{ comment }}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. Clear and concise.